# Fade in/out buttons on mouseover of an image with jQuery. A few bugs to work out

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

So, I essentially have what I want already, very simple, but there are some bugs. I just want so when you hover over an image, two left/right buttons appear on the image that allow you to click through other images. Then when you leave the image area (excluding the left/right buttons), the buttons fade out again. Here's what I've got:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#image-slider').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.next').fadeIn('50');
        $('.prev').fadeIn('50');
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $('.next').fadeOut('50');
        $('.prev').fadeOut('50');
    });
});
```

Bug #1: However, when you mouseover the image the buttons appear, and if you mouse over the buttons, they disappear. Naturally, of course they do, this is because I told them to fade away when I left the image area. First of all, I need them to stay visible even when you hover over them. So I need to somehow include the buttons as part of my image area in my javascript. That's the first problem/

Bug #2: This is a common problem I see in javascript. When you hover over the image, the buttons fade in, hover off, they fade out. Of course, there's a duration to this, and if you keep hovering in/out/in/out/in/out before the duration can finish, then when you let it fly, it will go on and off and on and off. How can I prevent this? So that is you hover out of the image area while the buttons are fading in, it just stops the animation sequence in its tracks so you don't get that continuous fading in/out.

Thanks in advance!
~ Jackson

ETA: the fix

I got it solved! A combination of your fix and @Pumou's.

I made another div just to wrap the two items and expanded it to cover the image, then I set the mouseover to be that div. Problem #1 solved.

I used puormo's .fadeTo() trick to solve problem #2.

Then, I used tweaks from everyone to shorten up the code so it was neat and tidy. Thanks to all!

I've decided on @jfriend00's solution. It's the shortest, great work!

Here's my final javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var b = $('.ps_next, .ps_prev');
    $('#slider-wrapper').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {    
       var check = ( e.type === 'mouseenter' ) ?
          ( b.stop(0,1).fadeIn(100)  ) :
          ( b.stop(0,1).fadeOut(100) ) ;
    });
});
```

Comment: Try making a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Do you realize that *each time* you hover the slider, *all elements on the page* are traversed *4 times* looking for elements with class-names of `next` and `prev`?

Comment: katspaugh mean ( I think ) that the best approach is to cache your elements in a var. `var btnNext = $('#image-slider .next');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem #2 can be fixed with `.stop()` which forces any previous animations to just to their conclusion before starting the next one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#imageContainer').hover(function() {
        $('.ps_next').stop(true, true).fadeIn(400);
        $('.ps_prev').stop(true, true).fadeIn(400);
    }, function () {
        $('.ps_next').stop(true, true).fadeOut(400);
        $('.ps_prev').stop(true, true).fadeOut(400);
    });
});
```

It may be better to use the `.hover()` jQuery function which handles both enter and leave rather than `mouseenter()` and `mouseout()`.

You can see both an example of `.stop()` and `.hover()` on [this jQuery doc page](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) doing almost the exact same thing you are.

For problem #1, I think we'd need to see the structure of your HTML to know how best to advise on that as their are several choices depending upon how things are structured.  You could also do the fadeOut on a delay that was cancelled if they hovered over the button so there was time to get the mouse to the buttons before they disappeared.  Or, you could use `.hover()` on a container that contained both image and buttons.

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Zk6rY/.

Shortened the code (as seen in the above jsFiddle) even more to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#imageContainer').hover(function() {
        $('.ps_button').stop(true, true).fadeIn(400);
    }, function () {
        $('.ps_button').stop(true, true).fadeOut(400);
    });
});
```

Comment: I've just posted my HTML, refresh.

Comment: I don't see where `#image-slider` is in your HTML?  Probably the easiest solution is to use .hover() on a container div that contains both image and buttons so the mouse is considered to be hovering on either and only fades out when it leaves both.  I added a little more to my answer that offers a couple options.

Comment: Thanks, the .stop(1,1) totally worked. THANK YOU SO MUCH! Still one problem left, in addition to a shortcut to all of this suggested by @roXon.

Comment: Also, in your fiddle, I don't see why "true,true" is necessary, "1,1" does the same thing in far fewer characters. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Technically the stop function calls for `Boolean` parameters.  Valid values for a boolean are `true` and `false`, not `1` and `0`.  `1` may work, but I would not suggest it.  The goal of writing code is to write correct and readable code.  Shortening code when it makes it less correct or less readable with no other benefit other than short is a bad idea.  Problem #1 is fixed in my answer and jsFiddle now too by using hover on a container div.

Comment: Yours is shorter, decided to go with yours. Thanks!

Comment: @roXon - changed the duration numbers.  Had just left it the way the OP had it.  It was defaulting to the default duration of 400ms which is apparently what the OP wanted anyway.

Comment: +1 for your changes jfriend00. Always have an eye awake for OP errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $buttons = $('.next, .prev')
    $('#image-slider').mouseenter(function(){
        $buttons.stop().fadeTo('50','1');
        $buttons.mouseenter(function() { $buttons.show(); });
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $buttons.stop().fadeTo('50','0');
    });
});
```

I have also used `stop();`. I've also shortened it to use one selector to select both buttons (in this case, it was set to the variable `$buttons`).

I noticed that if your mouse entered the image div, and then left, and then entered again, the buttons were fading in to 50% opacity because of the `stop();`. I fixed this by using the `fadeTo();` feature: the first one is the duration, which was set to 50 like yours, and the second one is the opacity to fade to (a number between 0 and 1).

I also solved the problem of keeping the buttons there when you hover over them. See this line:

```
$buttons.mouseenter(function() { $buttons.show(); });
```

This just uses `show();`, which gives the element `display:block;` on mouseover.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/MM4ba/1/
More about `stop();` here: http://api.jquery.com/stop
More about `fadeTo();` here: http://api.jquery.com/fadeto

**EDIT:** Updated the code so that it now uses jQuery's `hover();` function. Shorter code is always better.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $buttons = $('.next, .prev')
    $('#image-slider').hover(function(){
        $buttons.stop().fadeTo('50','1');
        $buttons.mouseenter(function() { $buttons.show(); });
    },
    function(){
        $buttons.stop().fadeTo('50','0');
    });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/MM4ba/2/
More on `hover();` here: http://api.jquery.com/hover

Comment: .fadeTo() is unnecissary I believe if you set the two .stop options to true like this: .stop(1,1) that flushes the animation cache or something, and jumpts to the end of the animation. Fixes the animation problem. Let me try out your way to fix problem #1, one sec.

Comment: Var works well, thanks. That solved a problem I didn't know existed.

Comment: @Jackson: No problem. Also, I tried `.stop(true, true);`, and I realized that it jumps to the end of the animation whereas mine simply stops at the current frame and fades out from there. It's up to you which effect you like better. ;)

Comment: Oh, I realize now how you did it. Great work! I'll test and you may get a green check, lul. But at least an up vote.

Answer (score 0):

### [DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/YvUcF/3/)

```
var b = $('.btn');

$('#image-slider').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {    
   var check = ( e.type === 'mouseenter' ) ?
      ( b.stop(false, true).fadeIn(300)  ) :
      ( b.stop(false, true).fadeOut(300) ) ;
});
```

(with your markup and the use of ternary-operators)

Comment: But... that tutorial says nothing about how to make buttons appear/disappear when hovering over the given image. How is it relevant?

Comment: check out tutorial two, I see it now. But that's not what I'm trying to do, your using a timer, a timer won't work in my case.

Comment: If you use 'mouseenter', make shure to use 'mouseleave' ;)

Comment: I see... you're putting them inside the container, then hovering over the container. I was using two separate elements, that's my problem. I got it all mixed up with this shadow effect I was doing. Thanks! Also, thanks for the typo fix about mouse leave.

Comment: You're welcome! Also, you can use 1 class instead of two, and free-up some lines of code! `btn ps_next` and `btn ps_prev` in your HTML and just use `.btn` for the jQuery fadeIn/Out

Comment: Interesting how nobody see that using `.fadeIn('50')` is totally INVALID. It acts like it's written `.fadeIn('slow')` -- Always use puse numbers: `.fadeIn(50)` or `.fadeIn('fast')` if you use 'letters'. WHERE 50 is in milliseconds... so use rather a gigher value!. Cheers, Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You all might be looking for this awsmness.....

`$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#content').hover(function () {
        $('.a').stop(true).fadeTo(500, 0.7);
        $('.i').stop(true).fadeTo(500, 0.9);
    }, function () {
        $('.a').stop(true).fadeOut(500);
        $('.i').stop(true).fadeTo(500, 1);
    });
    $('.a').hover(function () {
        $('.i').stop(true).fadeTo(500, 0.95);
    }, function () {
        $('.a').stop(true).fadeTo(500, 0.7);
        $('.i').stop(true).fadeTo(500, 0.9);
    });
});`

http://jsfiddle.net/Sourav242/p0z0oh82/